# compiling procedure in oracle, md5 encryption

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

What is wrong with this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE add_user (pid IN NUMBER, plogin IN VARCHAR2, ppassword IN VARCHAR, pemail IN VARCHAR)
IS
BEGIN
  DECLARE encryptedpassword VARCHAR(255);
  SET encryptedpassword := MD5(ppassword);
  INSERT INTO account(id, login, password, email)
  VALUES (pid, plogin, encryptedpassword, pemail);
END add_user;
```

For me it's look ok, but I'm getting errors:

> Error(6,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting
>   one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type
>        current
>   cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for
>   "INSERT" to continue.
>
> Error(8,13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case
>   declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise
>   return select update while with          << continue close current
>   delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute
>   commit forall    merge pipe purge

My table account looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE account 
(
  id NUMBER(6,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
  login VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL, 
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  register_data DATE,
  last_seen DATE,
  login_failed NUMBER(5,0)
);
```

Anybody, something?

Comment: Please don't use MD5 for hashing actual passwords. It [has significant flaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Comment: @Ben this is also not working: CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE add_user (pid IN NUMBER, plogin IN VARCHAR2, ppassword IN VARCHAR, pemail IN VARCHAR)
IS
DECLARE 
  encryptedpassword VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  encryptedpassword := MD5(ppassword);
  INSERT INTO account(id, login, password, email)
  VALUES (pid, plogin, encryptedpassword, pemail);
END add_user;

Comment: Remove the DECLARE... it's not required in compiled code - the `create or replace` is the declaration of the start of the block.

Comment: @Ben hmm weird "Error(5,24): PLS-00201: identifier 'MD5' must be declared"